# How to use Windows Authentication in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows-authentication

I'm not finding much documentation on how to use Windows Authentication in a WPF app.  I wouldn't have thought that it would be any different than in any non-WPF app, but it seems that it is.  I want to go into my project Properties -> Application and ensure that Windows Authentication is on, but that option is not available in a WPF app (as the following document confirms).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzdks800.aspx

If I ignore all that and just look at `My.User.Name` (VB), it is empty.  This tells me that somehow Windows Authentication is not enabled.

Seems like there is a concept I am missing; could someone point me in the right direction?

My plan is to use `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` to restrict access to certain parts of my app (or perhaps the entire app, by applying it to `Application_Startup()`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Itowlson's answer is correct, but also, in order to use the PrincipalPermissionAttribute on any method, you have to first make the windows principal the current principal by calling:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal)
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason this doesn't work in WPF is that these services are implemented in VB's `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` class, which isn't used in WPF applications.  To do the same thing yourself:

Call `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` to get the Windows user identity.  You can get the name from this.

If you specifically want to set the thread principal the way the VB Windows Authentication option does, call `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())` -- this is exactly what `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` does internally.

**EDIT:** If you prefer the My.User API, it looks like you should be able to do the same thing by calling `My.User.InitializeWithWindowsUser()`.  I haven't tested this though.