# WPF Windows Authentication Textbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, windows-authentication

I am developing a WPF Application in VB. I am using Windows Authentication. I have followed the steps listed here:

[How to use Windows Authentication in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521520/how-to-use-windows-authentication-in-wpf)

I would like to show what the username is in a text box which I do not know how to. Do I have to bind the text box?

Comment: What do you expect for an answer? Bind it to a label.

Comment: I would like to show who the current user is in a text box in my Application UI.

Comment: Do you want the logged in windows user automatically populated in Textbox?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I am trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Assuming that `Username` is the property representing your username, the following markup should bind the username to your `Text` property in your `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Username}"/>
```

**Note:** In order to automatically update your View when `Username` changes, make sure you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and set up the property correctly in order to notify the View when any changes were made.

Comment: My Textbox's name is Username. What should I be binding it to?

Comment: The name of your TextBox doesn't matter. The property where the username can be accessed needs to be bound.